# Define a Kerberos principal name for Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, confluent-schema-registry

I've activated SASL for my Kafka brokers. Schema Registry needs to be authenticated to connect to Kafka. [Here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/security/index.html) it says *"If you enable Kafka authorization, you must grant the Schema Registry service principal the ability to perform the following operations on the specified resources:"* How do I define a principal?

[There is](https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/schema-registry/docs/config.html#schemaregistry-config) a configuration `kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.service.name` but I'm not sure how to use it. Looks like it only needs a role or something, instead of a username password pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASL is just an authentication system that speaks many languages including kerberos.  `kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.service.name` is just that a name ... typically "kafka". (And should match your Jaas config, explained below)

Kerberos uses principles and Keytabs for authentication.  Kafka typically uses JAAS to manage it's Kerberos needs.  [Here's a typical jaas](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.0/authentication-with-kerberos/content/kerberos_kafka_configuring_kafka_for_kerberos_using_ambari.html) file for the kerberos broker:

```
   KafkaServer {
       com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
       useKeyTab=true
       keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka.service.keytab"
       storeKey=true
       useTicketCache=false
       serviceName="kafka" 
       principal="kafka/c6401.ambari.apache.org@EXAMPLE.COM";
       };
```

You will need a `principle` and a `keytab`.  You kerberos administrator should create [principle](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/platform-symphony/7.1.0?topic=file-creating-kerberos-principal-keytab-files) and [produce a `keytab`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/aadmin-17/index.html). Since those are outside the bounds of this question I've left them as links to explore.